# Cant change default python version inside docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Here is my situation, i got docker image. it has python3.6 as default and pip3 refer to python3.6. So i got new version of python3.7 that i got via curl.

My objective is install requirement.txt using python3.7 and pip that refer to python3.7. so what i do is

```
RUN curl -LJO http://someweb.com/new_python.zip

RUN yum -y install unzip
RUN mkdir -p /usr/bin/new_python
RUN unzip -o new_python.zip -d /usr/bin/new_python

RUN chmod +x  /usr/bin/new_python/python3.7
RUN echo 'alias python3=/usr/bin/new_python/python3.7' >> ~/.bashrc
RUN bash ~/.bashrc

RUN rm /<pip path>/pip3
RUN echo "unalias pip3"
RUN yum -y remove python3-pip && yum -y install python3-pip

ENV PYTHONPATH=/usr/bin/new_python/python3.7


RUN  python3 -m pip install \
    --requirement requirements.txt
```

but i got error

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2297' in position 77: ordinal not in range(128)
```

which indicate, it still use python3.6.
and then i try to change this command

```
RUN pip3 install \
    --requirement $PROJECT_PATH/requirements.txt
```

but got the same error

```
Exception:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
        status = self.run(options, args)
    UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2297' in position 77: ordinal not in range(128)
```

additional info, I cannot replace the python3.6 path because it still used by another feature.

is there any step that i miss, or could you give me direction what to do next? thank you

Comment: Do you use an official python docker image or something custom made? From the description provided it seems like you're using the container for 2 different features (/processes), which is something not usual in docker land. If at all possible I would try to run the python 3.6 and 3.7 features in different containers.

Comment: it custom made, it already has python3.6 and pip3. but the installation seems not using the usual way for pip3, because i cannot use yum -y remove pip3.. because the package not found.

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about a docker IMAGE and not a CONTAINER? You shouldn't adjust containers (they can be discarded by nature) while running. If you are indeed talking about an image, what do you base it on that it has 3.6 pre-installed? Technically it should only ever have 1 python version installed. Hence my suggestion to split it into multiple images.

Comment: The two other things I'd note in this setup are that most paths in Docker do not read `.bashrc` or any other shell dotfiles, so the `alias` does nothing; and running commands in a Dockerfile only ever makes images larger (even if it `RUN rm` things) so your final image will contain both versions of Python even if one is marked as deleted and isn't visible in the final filesystem.

Comment: @justLudo sorry i'm talking about docker image. okay let me try to split into multiply image..